# Excel: Referencing text within cell (rather than cell location) in VLOOKUP / Adding cell within table will auto add a cell on another tab?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a list of text names for example:

'Tab 1'!A1:A5'

A1 Red

A2 Blue

A3 Green

A4 Purple

A5 Brown

I want to run a VLOOKUP on Tab 2 to reproduce this exact list of text and also have it so that if I happen to add a cell within the list, it'll auto reproduce the new list on my separate tab.

So, if I add 'Orange' to A3, changing Tab 1 to be:

A1 Red

A2 Blue

A3 Orange

A4 Green

A5 Purple

A6 Brown

Is it possible to have this list auto add the Orange cell within my Tab 2?

Currently my formula looks like this on Tab 2:

=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT('Tab 1'!A1), 'Tab 1'!A1:C10,1,FALSE)

I'm getting a #REF as a return instead of 'Red'. Also, adding a new cell in the middle of the list doesn't seem to affect Tab 2.

Comment: you could just use =`tab1!A2` in tab2 to achieve that.... just copy the formula down past the end of your tab1 list

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that @Pynner’s approach is most suitable, but if you would rather mend yours then take out INDIRECT and when adding `Orange` also double-click the fill handle in ‘Tab 2’!A1 and, if necessary, extend the range to which the formula is applied.